# Non-trival solution for AX = 0 using eigen c++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

How can I get non-trival solution of `M*x=0` using Eigen linear algebra library.
I tried this but solution is all zeros.

```
Matrix<float,2,3> m ;
Matrix<float,2,1> y ;
m << 2 , 3 ,5 , -4 , 2, 3;
y(0,0) = 0;
y(1,0) = 0;
cout << "Here is matrix m:" << endl << m << endl;
cout << "Here is matrix y:" << endl << y << endl;
cout<<"solution: \n"<<m.fullPivLu().solve(y);
```

Comment: What is `m << 3` supposed to do?

Comment: it will populate matrix m row-wise.

Comment: What makes you think the solution is wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `m << 2 << 3 << 5 << ....` ?

Comment: No .I thought you meant m << 2 , 3 ,5 , -4 , 2, 3;. I don't say it is wrong I want non trivial solution

Comment: @LuchianGrigore They overloaded comma and `<<` operators in Eigen so you can initialize matrices using such syntax: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html

Comment: @user2947191 Please, let us know if the answer below does solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to solve `M * x = 0`, so it makes sense to return `x=0`. If you want to avoid this trivial solution, then you have to add additional constraints. For instance you might say that you want to minimize `|M * x|^2` subject to `|x|=1` in which case you end up with an eigenvalue problem (through Lagrange multipliers). Your solution is the eigenvector corresponding to the minimal eigenvalue. Using Eigen:

```
Matrix3f A = m.adjoint() * m;
Vector3f x = SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix3f>(A).eigenvectors().col(0);
```

Here I get:

```
x = 0.032739  0.851202 -0.523816
```

and `m * x` is in the order of `1e-16`.

Comment: I do not have any additional constraints,I have a matrix A which is divided into 2 parts A1 and A2 and I want solution X such that A1 * X = 0 , as I mentioned X should not be all zeros. Any other method or other library to do this is also work.

Comment: you don't have any additional constraint, but you HAVE TO add one! Typically, if x is a solution, then any scalar multiple will do as well. A naive solution would be to say that x[0]==1, but then you cut all solutions for which x[0] has to be zero or nearly zero. Without any additional prior,  the solution I suggested above is the most reasonable one.

Comment: @ggael Does this mean that if the smallest Eigenvalue > 0, the (non-trivial) null space is empty?

Answer (score 2):

You want to find a nonzero element in the kernel of your matrix (the kernel is the set of x such that Mx = 0), look in Eigen for a decompositon offering a kernel() method, for instance fullPivLu does:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1FullPivLU.html#a6e8f1d2fcbd86d3dc5a8a013b6e7200a